# Generators and Timeit... am I reading the results wrong?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, generator

I'm using Python 2.7.10.

I was going through a tutorial on generators, and understand that `xrange`, when called, returns a generator, so I am expecting it to be faster when calculating a sum.

I am confused about the whole 1 loop vs 10 loops and what `1 loop, best of 3` means considering there was only 1 loop?

How does `timeit` know how many loops to do, or is that a function of the code I'm applying `timeit` to?

I do not know how to interpret the results here.... Advice?

[image: timeit comparison]

Comment: Well, xrange is faster (it took less time) , can you elaborate on your question?

Comment: I have explained it in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result printing might seem a little weird unless you read the docs carefully.

The basic operation of timeit (or %timeit which uses the former) is:

```
\-- repeat timer loop n times (return best of t_i / m)
  \-- timed run (time t_i is measured)
    \-- statement loop
          (unless specified, m = 1, 10, 100, ..., until t_i > 0.2s
            t_i = sum(t_s)
          )
      \-- statement (t_s, time per statement)
```

What is displayed is `max(t_i)`.

1. First number (`n loops`) is the number of loops per timer run.
2. Second number (`best of m`) is the number of timer runs.
3. Third number is the time *per statement* execution of the best run from (2).

By default `timeit` runs the statement once for each timed loop and it runs three timed loops. The corresponding switch to change the number of timed loops is `-r`.

However, if the running time of a timer loop is less than `0.2` seconds, it repeats the timed statement inside a timer loop. First it goes up to `10` times, then `100` times, and so on. This is the first number. The corresponding switch to fix this number is `-n`.

So `range()` ran once for a single timer loop, because it took more than `0.2` seconds. A single `xrange()` sum, however, took less `0.2` seconds, so it was repeated 10 times, which was enough to push it over the boundary (ten runs took `0.682` seconds).

The resulting running time still is the running time of a *single* statement. The rest is typical benchmark smoothing stuff.

Comment: Let me see if I understand: if we set `-n` to 100, and `-r` is 3, then we will compare 3 averages of running the code snippet 100 times, and return the lowest value of those 3 averages?

Comment: @user3659451 Exactly. And the default is for `-n` to be dynamic and scale up via multiples of `10`.

Answer (score 2):

The time given by `%timeit` magic command of IPython is the time taken for the statement.

In case of `xrange` it only took 68.2 milliseconds, whereas `range` took 243 milliseconds , hence `xrange` really is faster than `range` as you are expecting.